# Upgraded from Rails 2.3.5 to 2.3.11 and am getting this error now: "uninitialized constant AssignmentsPresenter::OrderedHash

Tags: upgrade, ruby-on-rails-2

After upgrading, when I try to login to my Rails app, I get the following:

```
NameError in ApplicationsController#index
```

uninitialized constant AssignmentsPresenter::OrderedHash

RAILS_ROOT: /Users/jasonbodak
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

```
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:131:in `const_missing'
/Users/jasonbodak/janova/janova/lib/assignments_presenter.rb:4:in `present'
/Users/jasonbodak/janova/janova/app/controllers/applications_controller.rb:12:in `index'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `send'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/activesupport-2.3.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `send'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process_without_filters'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/Users/jasonbodak/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2011.03@janova-local_app/gems/actionpack-2.3.11/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:438:in `call'
```

Request

Parameters:

```
None
```

Show session dump
Response

Headers:

```
{"Content-Type"=>"",
"Cache-Control"=>"no-cache"}
```

Does this mean anything to anyone? Thanks.

Comment: can u be more efficient enough and paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. I don't know why upgrading Rails from 2.3.5 to 2.3.11 did this, but I had to change the line `assignments_by_status = OrderedHash.new` to `assignments_by_status = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new` and now it works just fine.